# How to make kind of dropdown in windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms, dropdown

I need to make a menu panel in windows forms. ( I'll attach a sample below).
In boostrap it's very easy with dropdowns. But I need to make it in windows forms.

Attention: 
I have a userControl form and I'm filling it with a header component (of type userControl) of height 30, under the header component I have another body component (of type usercontrol).

So far I tried to add a panel of height 80 to the header component that's filled with "Menu 1", "Menu 2", "Menu 3", "Menu 4". The visibility of the panel is false at start. Whenever I click "show button", its visibility gets set to true. However, the content of the panel is not seen fully as the height of the component is less than the panel's height.

1. This is how I add header and body components to the main panel

   ```
       mainForm.SuspendLayout();
       foreach (var userControl in mainForm.Controls.OfType<UserControl>())

       {

           mainForm.Controls.Remove(userControl);

       }
       mainForm.Controls.Clear();
       mainForm.Controls.Add(new HeaderComponentForm());
       newForm.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0,30);
       mainForm.Controls.Add(newForm);
       mainForm.ResumeLayout();
   ```
2. This is the click event of "show button"

   ```
   private void pbMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (pnlMenu.Visible)
       {
           pnlMenu.Visible = false;
       }
       else
       {
           pnlMenu.Visible = true;
           pnlMenu.BringToFront();
       }
   }
   ```

I want the panel to open up whenever "show button" is clicked for its full width without stretching the height of the header's component. 
[image: This is what I have right now. The white (in circle) is the panel I want to show at full height]

Comment: Are you trying to do complicated when it's natively included in winform's [ComboBox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox?view=netframework-4.7.2) ?

Comment: [MenuStrip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip?view=netframework-4.7.2) might be another alternative, depending of what you want

Comment: I could not design combobox in the way I want. Therefore, I added a panel and played with its visibility

Comment: basic winform isn't maybe the best solution for web-like desktop application, but there is, I guess, some nugget packages that allow you to do some HTML/CSS in a winform application.